# Adobe Flex DeepLinking

Tags: apache-flex

Why By default Flex does not come up with Deeplinking. we need to write separate code to achieve this. Could anyone please come up with a Simple example with brief description. Any hepl would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Flex can support Deeplinking by using BrowserManager.  Take a look at:
http://corlan.org/2008/06/25/flex-and-deep-linking/

Comment: Thanks for you reply.I have done a sampel. I succeed. Is there any chance to do it without browser manager. (I mean with out doing all these)

Comment: As I know, you cannot do this thing without browser manager or swfaddress.